# What to provide datatype for List of objects for storing it in table column

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create table for user in database
however I got stuck in providing datatype for list of address 
what should be the datatype used for Address column in SK_USER table for List adresses;

please find my DTO class-

```
package com.shopcart.dto;

import java.util.List;

public class User {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    private int age;
    List<Address> adresses;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Address> getAdresses() {
        return adresses;
    }

    public void setAdresses(List<Address> adresses) {
        this.adresses = adresses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", mobile=" + mobile + ", age=" + age + ", adresses="
                + adresses + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: A list of `Address`es here means that there are 2 tables and a 1 to Many relationship. One User can have multiple addresses. So you'd have a `userId` column in `Address` table and nothing in `User` related to address.

Answer (score 0):

yif you want to stome many address into single user you need to create one more table `Address` in which you can use UserId and address to store addresses. then create `AddressDTO`for address table. and use List, which store many object of `AddressDTO`.

but you need to add `id` column into user table and dto class.

for ex:

```
package com.shopcart.dto;

import java.util.List;

public class AddressDTO{

    private int userId;
    private String address;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }


    public int getUserIde() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId= userId;
    }

}
```